# criar funcoes java script após renderizar todas as partial views

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

Possuo um codigo em aspnet MVC com uma main view que pode chamar 3 partials view dependendo de onde o usuario clickar.

uma dessas partial view era parte da main view e possue um pluguin jquery sortable ui, enquanto estava na main view o pluguin funcionava perfeitamente porem quando separei para a partial view ele parou de funcionar, acredito que seja por causa dos metodos javascript / jquery que controlam o sortable ui que estao em um document.ready.

gostaria de saber se é possivel criar uma funcao jquery "documentAndAllPartialViewsLoad" uma vez que tentei até mesmo trocar as funcoes de jquery de lugar.

Answer (score 0):

Tente colocar a referencia do seu plugin na sua MasterPage... Isso pode estar acontecendo porque a referencia está sendo feita na sua Partial.

Answer (score 0):

onde fazes o include dos js?!

certifica-te que não estás a fazer os includes depois de renderizar as partials, e dentro das partials tentas usar por exemplo um jquery que ainda não está carregado.

se for esse o caso, carrega os js e só depois invoca as partials

Answer (score 0):

ola pessoal obrigado pela ajuda.

no caso o problema era que as funcoes na partial view estava dentro de uma tage

@section sript {} tag esta que nao funciona em partial views

sendo assim foi somente trocar a tag por   que tudo passou a funcionar.